# How to set the Euler angles(XYZ) of an arrow, from its components?

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, animation-nodes, mathematics

Given a vector(an arrow object) say $\vec A\,= \,P \hat{i} + Q \hat{j} + R \hat{k}$ , how to determine the corresponding Euler angles (XYZ) to be assigned to the vector so that it points in that specific direction. Or is there any another way to make that arrow point in that specific direction given by $\vec A$.

Comment: @batFINGER Yes it's a duplicate, please close

Comment: I have this Animation Nodes scrapbook with few pages on Euler angles (X,Y,Z). Skip to page #22 or #23 and search through pages ahead. Scrapbook is outdated. I am creating a new one for Blender 2.8  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1-n_R7yN2R-0ZUkj8xZyW5ObWzh_aEEFaRqv0SpC27V8

Comment: Another addon for maths to check out is Sverchok, a rival to Animation Nodes.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I didn't understand the solution linked in the answer, but  it just worked. I'll study this.

Comment: Link to tag Animation Nodes. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation-nodes  Check out works by Omar Emara (aka Omar Ahmad), 3DSingh, Rich Sedman, Jimmy Gunawan (who uses both AN & Sverchok), etc. For Animation Nodes, keep an eye on Omar Emara. He is not any math genius, but a MATHS WIZARD. He helps with AN addon development. Jimmy Gunawan has TONS of tutorials on AN & Sverchok in blogs and videos. Worth checking out. 3D Singh VFX's channel is a MUST-SEE.

Comment: @RitaGeraghty OMG thank you very much for the resources, will definitely make my life much easier